# How does the FAA define "Endorsement"?

Tags: faa-regulations, terminology, logbook-endorsements

I've looked in [Part 61.1](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c6d42a999c8a1e8843bb9bf2817d43f5&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_11&rgn=div8) and [Part 1.1](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65h.pdf) (definitions), and looked for it in [Advisory Circular 61-65H](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65h.pdf), "Certification: Pilots and Flight and
Ground Instructors", and a definition of "Endorsement" is not included among them.

What is the FAA's official way of defining what constitutes and endorsement?

Comment: Not sure if this is an exhaustive list, but [AC 61-65H](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65h.pdf) has a list of endorsements.

Comment: If it isn't defined in the FARs, then a common definition would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Page 1 of  [Advisary Circular AC61-65H](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65h.pdf) says:

> Endorsements represent training requirements completed and privileges
> granted. This AC helps airmen and instructors ensure that all training
> is completed and documented clearly and concisely. An endorsement
> marks and formalizes events such as an operating privilege or
> authorization granted or a limitation incurred.

Answer (score 2):

The best definition I have found is "an endorsement attests to the completion of ground and/or flight training required for airman certification testing, or for specific operating privileges." [FAA Resource Library](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/alc/libview_normal.aspx?id=6577). I don't believe the FAA explicitly defines endorsement in any of 14 CFR.